# PHP MongoDB $gt Filter Operator with findOne function

Tags: php, mongodb

I've been having difficulty with the MongoDB  operator using PHP Library.

```
$data =">1";                     
$val = substr($data ,1);
$filter = ["column_name" => ['$gt' => $val]];   
$test = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);              
$result = $collection->findOne($test);

//Echo return null value. No data from db
```

printing $result variable

I am getting No result on running the query. Please help. BASICALLY I JUST NEED TO KNOW HOW TO PASS $gt WITH findOne function.

Comment: You used `$val` as an array and then used `substr` on it? Maybe you wanted to run `substr` on a specific index?

Comment: basically, it will be work for different array. $data = array ("other"=>">1");, $data = array ("other"=>"<1");

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for passing filter. I have revised code

```
$data =">1";                     
$val = substr($data ,1);
$filter = ["column_name" => ['$gt' => $val]];                
$result = $collection->findOne($filter);
```

Basically, I have removed the "new \MongoDB\BSON\Query" and directly pass the filter to findOne